# When I click on page all the text boxes must be minimize

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am using focus to text boxes, When I click on 2nd box, 1st box will minimize and 2nd box will maximize and I will upload all the text in that box after filling the text,I will click on page all the text boxes must be minimize,So please tell me how to hide all text boxes which is mentioned in that page when I click on white space beside text boxes.

I used pagewrapper to hide but it did not work,so please help me from this.

Comment: okay that was lame.. please post some effort, code, [plunker](http://plnkr.co), [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

```
$(yourParentSelector).focusout(function(){
   toggleYourBox(off);
});

$(yourBox).focus(function(){
   toggleYourBox(on);
});
```

U may bind this functon on each box or just on the parent part

Answer (score 0):

There might be n no. of text boxes so you would need to handle it on blur of every text box. so you should use body click

```
$("body").on("click",function(event){
    var $element = $(event.currentTarget);
   if($element.attr("type") !== "text"){
     // write your code
   }
})
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you told them why you think `body [on]click` is the right answer (and not, for example `input [on]blur` or `[on]focusout`)

Comment: @santosh - id this solved your problem then please mark this as answered so it could help others too.